# Uploading a background image in new Xcode release

Tags: ios, xcode

So I trying to upload this image in Xcode. It looks all like it is working until I run the simulater which shows only white. It doesn't show the image. Any tips to how I can fix this or do you think it is just a glitch in the new Xcode? There error that I get is:

> Could not load the "weather.jpg" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier

Here are some pictures for reference:

[This is how it looks before I run it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mbnat.jpg)

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Your assets dict is in proper target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click the image and go to 'Show File Inspector'. Then check your project under 'Target Membership'. This should work.

The image is not currently added to your project.